# Update String to blob column of SQl Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. I have T_ABC_MASTER table which has column abcData and its image type in MS Server.
2. I want to update the following text to abcData.
3. Please help with any SQL script, not with the program, just need a query to do it.

**TEXT**

```
<note>
  <to1>abc`xyz</to1>
  <from2>local</from2>
  <heading>dadasd</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: `IMAGE`, `TEXT` and `NTEXT` are deprecated for centuries and should not be used anymore... Convert your data to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. In your specific case you should use the **native XML type**...

Comment: The image type will be removed from MS SQL in the future. Should use varbinary instead. And if you need a column to contain XML, wouldn't the XML type be a better match?  Also, do you need to update it from a file?

Comment: Thanks, both, @LukStorms I don't need to update it from a file, want as text.

Comment: Then use [update](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)? `update t_abc_master set abcData = '<xml></xml>' where id = @id'`.

Comment: And the image type is binary, so to select it as text you need to convert or cast it. For example like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880137/convert-image-datatype-into-varchar-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @LukStorms That it thanks , set abcData = convert(varbinary(max),convert(varchar(max), 'String to update')

Comment: It's stored in binairy, so you don't need to convert your string for the update. Just to display it as a string again when you select it.  That image type is normally intented for binairy files like jpg or gif.